# Spring Batch JPA skip insert on exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'm using Spring boot JPARepository saveall() to insert records in batch but it fails the whole batch on encountering any exception. How can I skip the exception in batch insertion and continue saving other records?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You have to iterate over the list and call `save` for each entry.

Btw. that's exactly what `saveAll` does:

That's the implementation of `SimpleJpaRepository`:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities) {

    Assert.notNull(entities, "Entities must not be null!");

    List<S> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in Spring Batch that is called chunk scanning, which basically allows you to "scan" a chunk for failed items and skip them if an exception occurs while writing the whole chunk. To activate this feature, you need to use a fault-tolerant step and declare the exception as skippable.

Please check the section [Configuring Skip Logic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#configuringSkip) in the reference documentation for more details about that feature. You can also find a sample [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples#chunk-scanning-sample).

Comment: I am accepting a list in rest api and want to persist the data from this list to database using saveAll(). I am not sure how spring-batch Item reader can read this data.

Answer (score 0):

saveAll() of `SimpleJpaRepository` uses @Transactional that boosts performance of saving the batch. More details here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-save-saveall

You can iterate over the entities yourself, make checking to avoid exception, and use save() to Insert or Update entities one by one.

Use @Transactional to get the same performance as saveAll()